# 'docker-compose run web' on Django in Docker container doesn't run website at localhost

Tags: python, django, docker

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
FROM registry.gitlab.com/datadrivendiscovery/images/primitives:ubuntu-bionic-python36-v2020.1.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /bbml

WORKDIR /bbml
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ADD . /bbml/

CMD [ "python", "./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8800" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8800"
    container_name: bbml
    volumes:
      - .:/bbml
    ports:
      - "8800:8800"
```

So I managed to get this to run properly by doing 'docker-compsoe run web' and go the standard "Starting development server" message at the bottom, but when I go to localhost:8800 it says "site can't be reached". What's going on?

Comment: Try replacing `python3` by `python` in command

Comment: I did and it crashed sadly

Comment: Try to run it with `docker-compose up web`

Comment: sadly still hangs : [

Comment: Can you shell into Docker (`docker exec -it <mycontainer> sh`) and execute the command (`./manage.py runserver`) manually what will happen?

Comment: I managed to fix it and reached a new problem

Comment: Hi could you share the output of the error, so we can know better what's the problem

Comment: @Kelvin there's no error being outputted it just says that the Django server is running but when I go to local host with Chrome just says not found

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
FROM registry.gitlab.com/datadrivendiscovery/images/primitives:ubuntu-bionic-python36-v2020.1.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /bbml
WORKDIR /bbml
COPY requirements.txt /bbml/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /bbml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services: 
    web:
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        container_name: bbml
        volumes: 
            - .:/app
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
```

Check your folders Permission and Run :

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Comment: I'm actually running on windows sadly :[ seems like people are much more successful with this on not window.

Comment: I got this error '$ docker-compose run web
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"python\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown'

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue. Docker will be running on a port you actually need to go to :8800 rather than localhost:8800